# Select after update in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, locking, sql-update, firebird, procedure

I am trying to write procedure without using directly lock statements.

```
SET TERM ^ ;
ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_GETSTATUS (
    IDTBL1 Integer )
RETURNS (
    STATUS Varchar(255) )
AS
declare variable t int;

BEGIN

   t=gen_id(RPUSING,1);
   update  TBL1 a set a.STATUS=cast('USINGBY' as varchar(255))||cast(:t as varchar(255)) where a.STATUS='free' and a.ID=:IDTBL1 order by a.LASTUPDATED rows 1 to 1;

   STATUS=cast('USINGBY' as varchar(255))||cast(:t as varchar(255));
   SUSPEND;
   END^
SET TERM ; ^


GRANT EXECUTE
 ON PROCEDURE PROC_GETSTATUS TO  SYSDBA;
```

When I'm selecting data from this by query like:

```
select * from TBL1 a where a.STATUS in (select b.STATUS from PROC_GETSTATUS(1));
```

It returns null. But this select

```
select * from TBL1 a where a.STATUS like '%USINGBY%'
```

in current transaction returns updated data. How to rewrite this query by one select to procedure in current transaction?

Comment: What happens when you remove the `SUSPEND`, this is not a selectable stored procedure (or at least: it shouldn't be), possibly the fact that it is selectable now due to the `SUSPEND` is causing the problem.

Comment: When I remove the SUSPEND, I don't know how to use data returned by execute procedure statement. (it not selectable). I tried to include (select * from TBL1 a where a.STATUS=...) into procedure and return  selected from TBL1 fields, but it also returns null.

Answer (score 0):

Why not return id of updated record and its new status?

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE PROC_GETSTATUS (
  IDTBL1 INTEGER)
RETURNS (
  ID INTEGER,
  STATUS VARCHAR(255))
AS
BEGIN
  FOR
    SELECT FIRST 1 a.id 
    FROM tbl1 a
    WHERE a.status='free' AND a.id=:IDTBL1 
    ORDER BY a.lastupdated 
    INTO :ID
  DO BEGIN
    STATUS = 'USINGBY' || gen_id(RPUSING,1); 
    UPDATE tbl1 a SET a.status = :STATUS
      WHERE a.id = :ID;
    SUSPEND;
  END 
END
```

Then use it in the query:

```
SELECT a.*, p.status FROM tbl1 a LEFT JOIN proc_getstatus(1) p ON a.id = p.id
```

Comment: No, I need update before select, because of if two different clients make firstly select same rows, then one of them will be overwritten by other update.

Comment: Then divide it into two separate operations (update and select) within one transaction.

Comment: SELECT will not see any changes made within the same statement.

Comment: Yes, but it will be two different statemets because gen_id will be generate two different ID for one value of TBL1.ID and TBL1.STATUS will be overwritten twice :(